# Most efficient way to remove all but the leftmost 1 in an arbitrary-length bitstring

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, mask, bit

It recently occurred to me that I don't know how to do this. Removing all bit the rightmost 1 bit of a string x can be done with `(x & ~(x-1))`. Does a similar expression exist for the leftmost 1 bit?

Comment: can you please provide an example with your current string and your desired string?

Comment: Well, there's `1<<x.bit_length()-1`, but I guess you'd like to avoid that method call.

Comment: Suppose the input is 00101101. The output should be 00100000.

Comment: I needed a little bit until I got it. You refer to [Python's bitstring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring/3.1.3)? IMHO, this is something you could've mentioned in your question. :-) Once you are editing your question, could you, please, leave a note how and why this applies to [tag:c] _and_ [tag:python]? I believe this is the case but, for me, it's not clear what you exactly intend to do.

Comment: A similar expression does not exist for the leftmost 1, because addition/subtraction "go left". Btw `(x & ~(x-1)) = x & -x`. You can do a log-step reduction though.

Comment: Sorry, I put both C and Python tags because I believe this question was language agnostic. But I suppose that perhaps I shouldn't have put any language tag at all.

Comment: Do you know [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)? For me, it looks like [Round up to the next highest power of 2](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2) looks like a promising start.

Comment: @harold. I see. When you say logstep reduction, you mean that the least number of steps for this leftmost operation would be O(logx)? As opposed to rightmost, which is O(1)

Comment: On one hand, I agree with "language agnostic". On the other hand, tagging bit manipulation with C is IMHO clever. I guess it's the best matching community for such questions... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I briefly skimmed that earlier. That function looks like it only works for 32-bit integers, however. I would like to be able to do this for an arbitrary-length bitstring.

Comment: Hmmm... In this case, IMHO, it can't be done without a loop. And that means, you have to process in pieces of bytes or words (e.g. an `unsigned int`) where you have trivial cases before the first non-zero word and other trivial cases after the first non-zero word. The first non-zero word itself can be handled as I already sketched.

Comment: May be, I'm focused a bit too much on C. C can do bitwise operations on `int`/`unsigned int` (and their `short`/`long` variations) only. A bitstring in C: that's an array of some integral type. (And, yes `char` is also such integral type though I didn't mention it. Recently, I saw a terrible discussion whether bitwise operations can be done on `char`s as its integral but the resp. operations usually convert to `int` and the result back...)

Comment: Without the python tag it just turns into a boring game of "using preprocessor macros to select the intrinsic supported by this compiler", there's nothing fundamental about it any more.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it can't be done without a loop.

At least in C, bit-wise operations are only supported for integral types (i.e. all variations of `int` and `char`) but not for arrays.

About `char`, I'm not sure as I saw just recently a hot discussion whether `char` might be considered. (It is usual in C that values of smaller types are implicitly converted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) for arithmetic or bit operations.)

Integer numbers of arbitrary length are not supported directly. They have to be resembled by arrays of an integral type.

That means, the algorithm needs actually three phases:

1. skip all array elements before first non-zero element
2. process first non-zero element with what I named "floor power of 2"
3. set all array elements after first non-zero element to 0

If 1. or 2. reaches end of array the remaining steps are skipped, of course.

The actual meaning of "before" and "after" depends on the [Endiannes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) which is used to store the arbitrary length number in array (i.e. beginning with least or most signigicant bits).

Actually, I believe, this has to be done in every higher language (than C) as well – either explicitly or "under the hood". (The exception would be if a certain CPU would support this by a specific op-code for this operation – IMHO hard to believe.)

So, this is what I got in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char Byte;

unsigned floorPow2Byte(unsigned v)
{
  /* set all bits below left most bit */
  v |= v >> 1;
  v |= v >> 2;
  v |= v >> 4;
  /* clear all bits below left most bit */
  v &= ~(v >> 1);
  /* done */
  return v;
}

void leftMostBit(size_t size, Byte bits[])
{
  size_t i = size;
  while (i--) if (bits[i]) break;
  if (i > size) return; /* wrap around -> everything was 0 */
  bits[i] = (Byte)floorPow2Byte(bits[i]);
  while (i) bits[--i] = 0;
}

void printBits(size_t size, Byte bits[])
{
  static const char *tbl[] = {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
  };
  while (size--) {
    printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 4], tbl[bits[size] & 0xf]);
  }
}

#define SIZE(ARRAY) (sizeof ARRAY / sizeof *ARRAY)

int main(void)
{
  /* samples */
  Byte bits1[] = { 0x00, 0xef, 0xbe, 0xad, 0x0b, 0x00 };
  Byte bits2[] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
  Byte bits3[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
  Byte bits4[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
  Byte bits5[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x80 };
  Byte bits6[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x80 };
  Byte bits7[] = { 0x00, 0x80, 0x80 };
  Byte bits8[] = { 0x80, 0x80, 0x80 };
  /* check it out */
#define DO(DATA) \
  printf("Input : "); printBits(SIZE(DATA), DATA); printf("\n"); \
  leftMostBit(SIZE(DATA), DATA); \
  printf("Output: "); printBits(SIZE(DATA), DATA); printf("\n")

  DO(bits1);
  DO(bits2);
  DO(bits3);
  DO(bits4);
  DO(bits5);
  DO(bits6);
  DO(bits7);
  DO(bits8);

#undef DO
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/GfdQ8e).

Output:

```
Input : 000000000000101110101101101111101110111100000000
Output: 000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000
Input : 111111111111111111111111
Output: 100000000000000000000000
Input : 000000000000000000000000
Output: 000000000000000000000000
Input : 000000010000000000000000
Output: 000000010000000000000000
Input : 100000000000000000000000
Output: 100000000000000000000000
Input : 100000000000000100000000
Output: 100000000000000000000000
Input : 100000001000000000000000
Output: 100000000000000000000000
Input : 100000001000000010000000
Output: 100000000000000000000000
```

The most notable part is probably the function `floorPow2Byte()`. This is strongly inspired by [Round up to the next highest power of 2](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#RoundUpPowerOf2) but I had to modify it a bit.

The idea is simple but the debugging costed unexpected much time. (TGIF)

---

Update:

The sample would obviously be more efficient when I had used `unsigned` instead of `Byte`. However, this wouldn't change the algorithm as whole.
The updated source:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* Assuming that size_t has "machine word width"
 * this might be the unsigned int type which might be process most
 * efficiently.
 */
typedef size_t Word;

Word floorPow2(Word v)
{
  assert(sizeof v <= 8);
  v |= v >> 1;
  v |= v >> 2;
  v |= v >> 4;
  if (sizeof v > 1) {
    v |= v >> 8;
    if (sizeof v > 2) {
      v |= v >> 16;
      if (sizeof v > 4) {
        v |= v >> 32;
      }
    }
  }
  v &= ~(v >> 1);
  return v;
}

void leftMostBit(size_t size, Word bits[])
{
  size_t i = size;
  while (i--) if (bits[i]) break;
  if (i > size) return; /* wrap around -> everything was 0 */
  bits[i] = floorPow2(bits[i]);
  while (i) bits[--i] = 0;
}

void printBits(size_t size, Word bits[])
{
  static const char *tbl[] = {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
    "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"
  };
  while (size--) {
    if (sizeof *bits > 1) {
      if (sizeof *bits > 2) {
        if (sizeof *bits > 4) {
          printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 60 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] >> 56 & 0xf]);
          printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 52 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] >> 48 & 0xf]);
          printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 44 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] >> 40 & 0xf]);
          printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 36 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] >> 32 & 0xf]);
        }
        printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 28 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] >> 24 & 0xf]);
        printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 20 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] >> 16 & 0xf]);
      }
      printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 12 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] >> 8 & 0xf]);
    }
    printf("%s%s", tbl[bits[size] >> 4 & 0xf], tbl[bits[size] & 0xf]);
  }
}

#define SIZE(ARRAY) (sizeof ARRAY / sizeof *ARRAY)

int main(void)
{
  /* samples */
  Word bits1[] = { 0x00, 0xef, 0xbe, 0xad, 0x0b, 0x00 };
  Word bits2[] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
  Word bits3[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
  Word bits4[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
  Word bits5[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x80 };
  Word bits6[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x80 };
  Word bits7[] = { 0x00, 0x80, 0x80 };
  /* check it out */
#define DO(DATA) \
  printf("Input : "); printBits(SIZE(DATA), DATA); printf("\n"); \
  leftMostBit(SIZE(DATA), DATA); \
  printf("Output: "); printBits(SIZE(DATA), DATA); printf("\n")

  DO(bits1);
  DO(bits2);
  DO(bits3);
  DO(bits4);
  DO(bits5);
  DO(bits6);
  DO(bits7);

#undef DO
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

The many `if`s may feel uncomfortable but a good C compiler should recognize that the conditions are compile-time computable and will optimize them "away" respectively.

Compiled and tested with VS2013 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
Input : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010101101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001011111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111011110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Output: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Input : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111111
Output: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Input : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Output: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Input : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Output: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Input : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Output: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Input : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Output: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Input : 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Output: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: I realized that it's actually rather "floor power of 2" and renamed it resp.